# Call Multibranch pipeline A from Multibranch pipeline B located in 2 different folders in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am working on organizing my jobs using folder in Jenkins.

This is how my multibranch pipelines are organized.

```
Folder-A/job/Folder-B/job/Folder-C/job/Folder-D/pipeline-projectX

Folder-A/job/Folder-B/job/Folder-E/job/Folder-F/pipeline-projectY
```

Individually, both are working fine. When I am trying to call **pipeline-projectY** from **pipeline-projectX** as a post build action, it is giving error as:

hudson.AbortException: No item named found.

Most probably, the path of the project I am giving is wrong-

```
success {
          build job: '/Folder-A/job/Folder-B/job/Folder-E/job/Folder-F/pipeline-projectY'
        }
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove "job" from the path for projectY and also call it for a specific branch. Otherwise, it was giving `Waiting for non-job items is not supported`.